# Table in R like "matryoshka"

Tags: r, user-interface

How can I make table for show in R like "matryoshka"?
For example:
For the first time user see in table bank name. Then if user clicks on the name, a list of departments will appear below. If clicks on department, then user can see managers of that deparment below and so on...
Is this real for R?

Comment: So the real question is how to make a hierarchal table or tree type thing. I don't know R though, hopefully someone else knows how to do this.

Comment: the reactable package offers this:
https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html#multiple-groups-1

Comment: zoowalk, thank u a lot. It's what I search)